# How to draw a border around a subset of nodes？

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, automation

I need diagrams like this:
[image]

I've automated the "black" part but could not figure out how to do it with the red border; my current version is this:
[image]

Here are latex ""code"" which i have written as following,

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds}

\newcount\prevnode

\def\EDynkin#1{
\prevnode=0
\node (1) at (2,0) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\node (2) at (0,1) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\node (3) at (1,0) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\node (4) at (0,0.5) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\node (5) at (-1,0) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\node (6) at (-1,0.5) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\draw (1) -- (3) -- (4)-- (6);
\draw (2) -- (4);
\draw (2) -- (3);
\draw (2) -- (6);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\draw (1) -- (2);

\foreach\kthweight[count=\k] in {#1}{
\ifnum\k=1\node at (2,0) {\scriptsize\kthweight};\fi
\ifnum\k=2\node at (0,1) {\scriptsize\kthweight};\fi
\ifnum\k>6
\node (\k) at (4-\k,0) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {};
\draw (\k) -- (\the\prevnode);
\fi
\ifnum\k>2\node at (4-\k,0) {\scriptsize\kthweight};\fi
\global\advance\prevnode by1
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\EDynkin{6,3,5,4,2,1}
\node (box) [draw=red,rounded corners,fit = (3) (4) (2)] {};
\node (box) [draw=red,rounded corners,fit = (1) ] {};
\node (box) [draw=red,rounded corners,fit = (5) (6)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it. How to add title beside with Square.For example, M1,M2 M3. Thans a lot.

Comment: hi, and welcome among us. please use ``` code ``` when typing code next time. thanks

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear, what is your problem. Result of provided MWE is different from sketch, what is wrong with red, does all vertex (black circles) contain numbers), why number 1 and 4 are out connected vertex? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I do not understand what you are aiming for. Why don't you just use, for example, `\node (1) at (2,0) [circle,draw,radius=1em] {1};` to draw a node is essentially an encircled 1? I can hardly follow the logic of your code, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing what is your problem ... The following MWE try to reproduce your sketch where for vertices are use circle containing numbers:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=3 
  V/.style = {circle, draw,radius=1em, inner sep=2pt},
FIT/.style = {draw=red,rounded corners,fit = #1}
                    ]
% vertices
\node (1) [V] {1};
\node (4) [V, below right=of 1] {4};
\node (2) [V, below left =of 4] {2};
\node (3) [V, above right=of 4] {3};
\node (5) [V, below right=of 4] {5};
\node (6) [V, right=of 3] {6};
% groups of vertices,m red rectangled
\node[FIT = (1) (2)] {};
\node[FIT = (3) (4) (5)] {};
\node[FIT = (6) (5.south -| 6)] {};
% arrows for vertices conections
\draw   (1) -- (2) -- (5) -- (4) -- (1)
        (1) -- (3) -- (6) -- (5) -- (3) -- (4);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If problem is your definition of command for drawing connected vertices, than  move code for drawing vertices and connections between them to your new command (sorry, I don't understand its logic).

**Addendum:**
Consider your comment:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=3 
dot/.style = {circle, fill, radius=2pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
              label={[font=\scriptsize]#1}},
FIT/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, inner sep=2ex, fit = #1},
every label/.append style = {fill=white, inner sep=1pt}
                    ]
% vertices
\node (1) [dot=left:M1] {1};
\node (4) [dot=left:M4, below right=of 1] {4};
\node (2) [dot=left:M2, below left =of 4] {2};
\node (3) [dot=:M3, above right=of 4] {3};
\node (5) [dot=below:M1, below right=of 4] {5};
\node (6) [dot=right:M1, right=of 3] {6};
% groups of vertices,m red rectangled
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\node[FIT = (1) (2)] {};
\node[FIT = (3) (4) (5)] {};
\node[FIT = (6) (5.south -| 6)] {};
}
% arrows for vertices conections
\draw   (1) -- (2) -- (5) -- (4) -- (1)
        (1) -- (3) -- (6) -- (5) -- (3) -- (4);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add title beside with square, For expilicity, M1, M2 and M3.

Comment: @Yang, by labels. But, are in the such a cases vertices empty circles or black dots?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are aiming for. Typically, I would first draw the nodes that have at contents the numbers and as shape are circles with a border, then connect these nodes and eventually draw the red boxes using the `fit` library:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\node (1) at (0,1) [circle, draw] {1};
\node (2) at (0,0) [circle, draw] {2};
\node (3) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {3};
\node (4) at (1,0.5) [circle, draw] {4};
\node (5) at (2,0) [circle, draw] {5};
\node (6) at (4,1) [circle, draw] {6};

\draw (1) -- (2) -- (5) -- (6) -- (3) -- (1)
      (1) -- (4) -- (5) -- (3) -- (4);

\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (1) (2)] {};
\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (3) (4) (5)] {};
\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (6)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you want to automate things, but I don't really get from your code in which way things should be automated.

Labels can be added to the red boxes like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\node (1) at (0,1) [circle, draw] {1};
\node (2) at (0,0) [circle, draw, radius=1em] {2};
\node (3) at (2,1) [circle, draw, radius=1em] {3};
\node (4) at (1,0.5) [circle, draw, radius=1em] {4};
\node (5) at (2,0) [circle, draw, radius=1em] {5};
\node (6) at (4,1) [circle, draw, radius=1em] {6};

\draw (1) -- (2) -- (5) -- (6) -- (3) -- (1)
      (1) -- (4) -- (5) -- (3) -- (4);

\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (1) (2), label={left:M1}] {};
\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (3) (4) (5), label={[red]center:M2}] {};
\node[draw = red, rounded corners, fit = (6), label={below:M3}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add title beside with square, For expilicity, M1, M2 and M3. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Yang Like this (see my edit)?

Comment: If M2  is in the square, it will be perfect!

Comment: @Yang You can place labels `left`, `right`, `above`, `below`, or at the `center`. You can change the color of the label by adding options to the label. If you don't like this, just omit this.